# Find out changed line numbers from git diff

Tags: git, git-diff, line-numbers

I need to know the changed line numbers between two commits (`HEAD~1 and HEAD`) to a repo

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
```

returns information in a confusing diff format

I was able to identify newly added files or deleted files by looking at their markers in git diff (ie `--- /dev/null` and `+++/dev/null` meaning added, deleted)

Is it possible to identify the lines numbers in the modified files

The need for me is

```
path/to/file/MyClass1.java
23-56
59-60
72-74

path/to/file/MyClass2.java
1-34
54-56
```

23-56 , 72-74 and 59-60 are the line/range of lines (denoted as line number) changed between HEAD~1 and HEAD

PS: few of the leads which I found on other SO questions seems to be outdated
Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-diff

Comment: @symlink I had in past visited the same link and my difficulty is not in generating diff rather it's getting it in the format I want which I explained in my question

Comment: You might think about the fact that the unified diff format that Git uses is the product of some 40 years of evolution, going from an original very-terse and fragile format that is remarkably similar to what you're asking for, to the current comprehensive and fairly robust format. In other words, you might find `git diff` output confusing (many do at first) but it's what people using these tools in practice for many decades have settled on, more or less, as best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give the diff for modified files between the two revisions `HEAD~1` and `HEAD`

```
git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M HEAD~1 HEAD
```

Using `grep` utility, the modified lines and index can be removed from the output

```
git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M HEAD~1 HEAD  | grep -v -e '^[+-]' -e '^index'
```

The output :

```
diff --git a/some/file b/some/file
@@ -startline1,count1 +startline2,count2 @@
...
```

On further processing using `sed` utility, the final command is :

```
git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M HEAD~1 HEAD | \
grep -v -e '^[+-]' -e '^index' | \
sed 's/diff --git a.* b\//\//g; s/.*@@\(.*\)@@.*/\1/g; s/^ -//g; s/,[0-9]*//g; s/\(^[0-9]*\) +/\1-/g;'
```

and the output should look like this

```
/some/file1
startline1-startline2
/some/file2
startline3-startline4
...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man!
Answer verified with git version 2.25.0
Working as I wanted

Comment: @anon-sAI Please note that it is quite possible that it might fail in some cases , I recommend you to use the second command `git diff --unified=0 --diff-filter=M HEAD~1 HEAD  | grep -v -e '^[+-]' -e '^index'` if you want to be on the safer side, but in the interest of the output format you have suggested, I have asked a question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/582559/408757) to see if it can be further improved and to find out any case it might fail

Comment: Noted! Would update the failure cases in this thread if I come across any

Comment: @anon-sAI safer alternative as it doesn't involve post-processing : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582649/408757

Comment: Better one @Saurabh